# Is there a mechanism to delay traffic in ProxyMan?

Tags: proxy

Let's assume we have an HTTP/HTTPS traffic hitting an endpoint via GET request. The endpoint then returns a response. Is there a mechanism to delay the response for X seconds(assuming X < request timeout)? I have tried using BREAKPOINT already intuitively and was wondering if there is a direct solution for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Using the Network Condition.

Right-Click on the request you'd like to delay -> Tools -> [Network Condition](https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/network-throttling) -> Create a rule with the 3G profile.

[image: Slow network with Proxyman]

2. The Network Condition will be applied to the entire domain. If you'd like to add the delay for a particular request (path + query), you might check out the [sleep()](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/snippet-code#response-delay-with-sleep-function) func from the Scripting tool.

```js
function onResponse(context, url, request, response) {
  console.log("Start sleep");
  
  // Sleep 5 seconds
  sleep(5000);
  
  // Done
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was exactly looking for the second solution.